# CDN Implementation with Regex killing CPU under duress

Tags: regex, cdn

We are trying to setup use of CDN on our website to gain benefit of bandwidth and page load speeds. This is being done through HttpModule running Regex against html just before going to browser. This works great with not too much traffic with faster load times and decreased bandwidth. But when we tried some stress tests it was causing CPU to max out on our powerful machine where the CPU was only at 50% under same load with it turned off.

We cannot use Jquery as that is too late in the process and there is a Head tag where we would be able to make a base change but that is to all links on the page but we cannot redirect hyperlinks etc to the CDN also.

Has anyone done something similar and found a more efficient way of making the changes to the URL paths?

Comment: Until proven otherwise, I would bet on catastrophic backtracking. Please show your regexes and an excerpt of the data you're matching them against, then we can see how/why the matches are so inefficient.

Answer (score 2):

A simple RegEx expression generally requires more CPU time to process than the equivalent done by string processing functions.

Some (rare) RegEx expressions have horrible performance characteristics.

Lacking further information, I would suggest looking at achieving what you want using string functions.

You will have to post your expression and requirements for more detailed guidance.

Comment: Sample regex is (<(?:{0}).+?)({1})=('|"")(?:\/)([^>]+\.(?:{2}))((?:'|"")|(?:\?[^>]*('|"")))([^>]*?>)   where 0 is the Html Tags to match, 1 is then the attributes e.g. href and src and then 2 is the file extensions to match  - Thank you for the reply though

Comment: Note, I would suggest such "horrible" (that is exponential time complexity) are not so rare – they are very easy to create.

Comment: HI Richard, thanks for the info. I am not well versed in regex could you make a recommendation that allows the same flexibility or are you proposing that the CPU hit is just because we want to much flexibility but the Regex is about right for its function?

Comment: @Richard: Probably so (I hardly use RegEx because I usually find myself working on performance critical code).  However, I would suspect that most commonly used RegEx perform decently (e.g. "validate" email, zip, SSN, phone number, etc.).

Comment: @barney3012 you would need to specify what (rather than how) you are changing within the document and also why. Ie. solution options should come from requirements (and their motivation) not reverse estimated from a current solution.